# Loading data using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of states in a drop down menu (`select`). I have a page for each state. Each page has the state abbreviation as a name, for example: **Alabama** is `al.htm`. I want to load the contents of **htm** depending on the selection of the state name; and the same for each state. In other words, if I select **New York**, I should see the information in **ny.htm**.

To load the data that is in different pages?

Comment: Where did you want this data to load? You could you some sort of iframe to display that specific page.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite vague, so this answer makes a few assumptions. Firstly, I'm assuming the `value` of each `option` is the abbreviation e.g.:

```
<select id="yourSelect">
    <option value="al">Alabama</option>
</select>
```

Next, I'm assuming you want to load the content of the pages into a specific element on your page, and that you want this to happen any time the selection changes:

```
$("#yourSelect").change(function() {
    $("#whereToLoad").load(this.value + ".htm");
});
```

Comment: If I have a map and I create an image map, how can I display the same page by clicking on the state in the map?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It sounds like you have a completely different question so you should probably post a new question asking it.